# Weird NSDateFormatter result

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

Why on Earth would the year be coming out wrong here?

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd";
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2013-12-31 00:00:00 +0000
[formatter stringFromDate:date]; // 2014-12-31
```

I had similar problems on New Year's Day with another app and now I'm seeing it again... Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you probably want `"yyyy"` instead of `"YYYY"`

From the [Unicode Date Format Patterns documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

> y: Year.
>
> Y: Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars). … May not always be the same value as calendar year.

The date 2013-12-31 is part of the first week of 2014, not the last week of 2013. That's why you get 2014 as the year component.

Comment: Gah! Nice one. That's exactly it.

Comment: I am tempted to type a curse word here.